# Kendo Angular Toolbar - Click on Overflow button is not working properly

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a requirement where I need to use Kendo Toolbar in multiple widgets. But if user clicks on one of the overflow button and again clicks on some other button then the page scrolls back to the previously clicked overflow button.

Stack Blitz to reproduce the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-41imns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on overflow button on widget, do not click on Export to excel
2. then scroll down to the last widget and again click on overflow button.
3. then you should navigate to previously clicked toolbar

Comment: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/3389